# Array in array not correctly interpreted by foreach loop in Puppet erb

Tags: arrays, variables, templates, foreach, puppet

```
  $array_one = [
    'one',
    'two'
  ]

  $variables = [
    'world',
    'a',
    'b',
    $array_one
  ]

  file { '/tmp/test':
    content => template("test/test.erb")
  }
```

test.erb

```
<% @variables.each do |variable| %>
  hello_<%= variable %>
<% end %>
```

results in:

```
  hello_world

  hello_a

  hello_b

  hello_onetwo
```

while it is an array according `notify {$variables:}`:

```
Notice: b
Notice: /Stage[main]/Test/Notify[b]/message: defined 'message' as 'b'
Notice: world
Notice: /Stage[main]/Test/Notify[world]/message: defined 'message' as 'world'
Notice: one
Notice: /Stage[main]/Test/Notify[one]/message: defined 'message' as 'one'
Notice: a
Notice: /Stage[main]/Test/Notify[a]/message: defined 'message' as 'a'
Notice: two
Notice: /Stage[main]/Test/Notify[two]/message: defined 'message' as 'two'
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.17 seconds
```

Comment: Where is the question here? You should raise a bug on the puppetlabs bug tracker if you'd like to get a fix for it: [http://tickets.puppetlabs.com](http://tickets.puppetlabs.com)

Comment: @Sekm [Issue](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-3860) has been created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Ruby loop does exactly what you ask of it. The `notify` resource implicitly flattens the array, apparently, so the `erb` equivalent would be

```
<% @variables.flatten.each do |variable| %>
  hello_<%= variable %>
<% end %>
```